# Soap UI Groovy - Run test step on failed assertion

Tags: soap, groovy, soapui, assertion

I have a SOAP project and wish to run one test step if an assertion fails and another if it passes.

Please see the following pseudocode:

```
If assertion of node fails  
       run testStep "Activate"  
Else
       run testStep "Deactivate"
```

Is this possible?!

Thanks

Comment: Possible.  Can you specify the structure of your test case and their step types?

Comment: REX8, Have you got chance to try the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that the test case has following steps.

1. Step1
2. Step2
3. Step3

And here you wish to execute one of the 2nd or 3rd step based on the result of Step1.

So, add `Script Assertion` to the **Step1** as mentioned below.

Please note that the focus of the below script is to enable to disable. You need to create the condition when to activate and which step.

I am just giving a sample condition for the demo.

```
//Closure to enable to disable the test step
def changeStep = { name, isDisable ->
    context.testCase.testSteps[name].disabled = isDisable
}

def value = 1
def map = [:]
//Change the step names as needed to your environment.    
if (1 == value) {
    map['Step2'] = true
    map['Step3'] = false
} else {
    map['Step2'] = false
    map['Step3'] = true

}
map.collect {k, v -> changeStep(k, v)}
```

Also keep in mind that when the value is `true`, respective step is disabled. `false` to enable the step.

Now, when the test case is executed, the unwanted test step is automatically disabled so that it won't run.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below code and see it works for your requirement :

```
def data = ["true","false"]

for(int i=0;i<data.size();i++)
{
    if(data[i] == "true")
    {

         testRunner.runTestStepByName("customer - activate")
        }
    else if(data[i] == "false")
    {

         testRunner.runTestStepByName("customer - deactivate")

        }
    }
```

Here "customer - activate" and "customer - deactivate" are the names of the Test Steps